# Does XNA effectively replace Managed Directx?

Tags: .net, directx, xna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison between XNA and DirectX (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514872/comparison-between-xna-and-directx-c)

The subject speaks for itself.

Does XNA effectively replace Managed DirectX?

We have a few projects using managed DirectX in VB.NET. I was considering porting one over to XNA, but wonder whether it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does XNA effectively replace Managed DirectX? According to the [wikipedia entry for MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) it does. At least for game development purposes.

XNA aims to be a framework for making games, so it is easy to get started. Managed DirectX is "just" a managed wrapper over the APIs, so you have more freedom but probably have to do more framework style code yourself.

Also, now there's the [API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), which provides managed wrappers around the latest DirectX APIs. To me that sounds like an updated version of what Managed DirectX used to be.

This answer is dated as XNA is no longer officially supported. Anyone interested in using DirectX from managed code should check out [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) in addition to the suggestions in the other answers to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, especially regarding the API Code Pack. I just wonder if they'll update the DirectX portion of the Code Pack as new versions of DirectX come out. Something tells me MS will leave it at the version of DirectX that ships with Win7 (at least until Win8).

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same. One thing you should consider is that Managed DirectX will no longer be developed. So if you change to XNA, you support for DirectX 9, but not DirectX 10 (or 11 soon). So if you really want to replace Managed DirectX, you should have a look at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org). It's not (yet) as large as MDX, but this will change and everything should be supported. The best thing is, it supports also DirectX 10. I used it myself and I guess it's work a look.