# DirectX managed or unmanaged?

Tags: directx, unmanaged, managed

I need basic information about DirectX. Is it a managed API or Unmanaged? Can someone provide me some link etc. explaining this?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502390/does-xna-effectively-replace-managed-directx/1502418#1502418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164112.aspx) describes how DirectX can be used in a managed (and it looks like unmanaged too!) way.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

DirectX is unmanaged, but there are [managed wrappers/bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xna/default.aspx) for it as well.

Comment: Seems like this resource doesnt exist anymore.