# DirectX in IronRuby

Tags: directx, ironruby

I'm thinking about writing a game using DirectX, and I'm considering using IronRuby.

- Is IronRuby stable enough to use in production?
- Does IronRuby work well with DirectX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is ready for production. Version 1.0 is available since April 2010. Please use it and give us feedback ([link text](http://ironruby.codeplex.com)). Regarding DirectX compatibility - I haven't tried t owrite anything but from a quick look at the managed DirextX API there seems to be no reason why it won't work. Most of the .NET APIs that are usable from C# or VB.NET are accessible from IronRuby as well. There are a few exceptions, some APIs rely on static types, but that shouldn't be the case for DirectX. We are working on enabling those as well in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I cannot address the IronRuby part of your question, but for managed DirectX, you could check out [API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), which provides a managed wrapper for DirectX.

This question has additional details on managed DirectX [Does XNA effectively replace Managed Directx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502390/does-xna-effectively-replace-managed-directx/1502418#1502418)