# Is Managed implementation of DirectX discontinued

Tags: managed-directx

I just wanted to know whether Microsoft has dropped the Managed implementation of DirectX as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514872/comparison-between-xna-and-directx-c) is it true?

Please if you can get any link directly from Microsoft website about the same.

Comment: I can't provide any explicit link saying so, but it appears that Microsoft will invest most of their effort in XNA over the Managed DirectX wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The Managed DirectX development was basically stopped.  You can see [references to the fact that Managed DirectX 2 will never ship](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmiller/archive/2006/04/12/575225.aspx) on blogs, etc, and it was pulled from the DirectX SDK.

There are better options - [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/), for example, wraps all of the DirectX/Direct3D types, including the DX10/11 interfaces.  It also has a much cleaner design than the original Managed DirectX.

If you need a "Microsoft" sponsored option, you could use [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) or the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) for managed DirectX development.  However, neither of these options provides the full DirectX API.